# How do I create my own database for SQL and Tableau?

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I am completely new in this field. I want to learn more outside office hour, so I can not use office server. I want to have my own database to practice on using SQL and Tableau. How do I achieve that?

[what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZwGI.png)

So in that pic, I want to have the option circled by red line. Having that option means I can create my own sql on tableau by editing the part circled by orange line.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Minor frame challenge, you might [like I did] be able to ask for permission to practice on the work data after hours.

Comment: @NicoHaase, I made an excel spreadsheet on microsoft OneDrive. When I use the database and tables provided by my company there's a "new custom SQL" option on the left pane right below list of tables, in data source tab of the tableau workbook. When I use my onedrive excel or tableau sample dataset, this option does not appear. I need that option to appear, so I'm thinking about creating my own database using whatever free server available.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau already provides sample Datasets that everyone can use to practise building sheets and dashboards. Take a look at the Sample - Superstore dataset for example

[image]

More info on that dataset [here](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000CWeX8SAL/sample-superstore-sales-excelxls).

It also provides Geographic data so you can practise building maps and geographic aggregations. Some examples are found in Tableau's Sample Workbooks that are based on the datasets I've described

[image]

In terms of practising SQL - you haven't specified which flavour of SQL but you can start with Oracle which is very well known and used. You can create an account in Oracle SQL Live which will give you access to several online sample databases provided by Oracle where you can practise your SQL queries.

An advantage of using Oracle Live SQL is that you won't have to concern yourself with setting up the database as it will already be ready to use. Does that help?

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1000

Comment: Thank you. But that does not really give me what I need.When I use the database and tables provided by my company, there's a "new custom SQL" option on the left pane right below list of tables, in data source tab of the tableau workbook. I've tried creating excel on onedrive, but when I use it on tableau, the 'new custom SQL' does not appear. Same with when I try to use tableau sample dataset. I need that option to appear, so I'm thinking about creating my own database using whatever free server available.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of this "new custom SQL" option in Tableau? The times I've used a custom SQL was when I was trying to join new data to an existing dataset in Tableau, and I had to use a custom JOIN expression as my fields weren't yet ready to be used in JOINS (they needed extra manipulation)

Comment: I think definitely it's best if you add screenshots of the setups you are trying to achieve?

Comment: So basically I want to practice on extracting data from database and tables while on tableau, using the 'new custom sql' option. Since I can't use my work server and everything I've tried doesn't work, I was thinking that maybe I just need to create my own database on some server. I have absolutely no idea how that works. Hence, my question....

Comment: You can create a database with SQLlite and DB Browser (https://sqlitebrowser.org/) and then save it locally I guess. You can then try to import it to Tableau? Would that help?

Comment: But my comment still stands, you should be able to show what you've already tried, give screenshots so others can be more familiar with what you've already seen/tried.

Comment: Yes. I updated my question and added picture

Comment: awh. I already downloaded Oracle :( Is it very different if I want to achieve what I describe?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to download sample databases directly, you can do so from Kaggle for example.

Search for [**SQLite files**](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets?fileType=sqlite) and download one?

[image]

For example, you can use the following dataset, just make sure you download the database option

[image]

https://www.kaggle.com/crowdflower/twitter-airline-sentiment

You can then use [this article](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/customsql.htm) to read more about how Tableau lets you connect to subsets of a database using the "Custom SQL" option you were talking about

Comment: Hey @tatertots42 did this solve your question?